# Strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continued-fractions, monotone-functions

It [seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017324/strictly-increasing-function-from-reals-to-reals-which-is-never-an-algebraic-num) this question is duplicated...Still I would be grateful for any hint to my second question.

Does there exist a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., from real numbers to irrational numbers? It cannot be surjective, since otherwise one can show that it is continuous and obtain a contradiction, but without assuming surjectivity I have not found a contradiction.

I do have a candidate function with that property by translating decimal expansion to continued fraction. More precisely, define a function $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ as follows. Let $x\in(0,1)$ with decimal expansion $0.a_1a_2a_3...$, define $f(x)$ to be $[0;1,1+a_1,1,1+a_2,...]$. As far as I understand infinite continued fraction must represent irrational number, and it seems $f$ preserves order. Is this a correct example?

More generally, what subset of reals can be the image of strictly increasing function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is fine so long as you specify some way to disambiguate which decimal expansion to use for numbers with a terminating one. You could also solve this by taking the decimal digits and interleaving them with those of some irrational number - this would never yield a repeating decimal and would more obviously be increasing.

You can work out an answer to your more general question too:

> A set $S$ is the image of an increasing function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ if $S$ has at least two elements and for every point $x$ not in $S$, exactly one of the following holds:
>
> 1. There is a maximum element in $S\cap (-\infty, x)$.
> 2. There is a minimum element in $S\cap (x,\infty)$.
> 3. The set $S\cap (-\infty, x)$ is empty.
> 4. The set $S\cap (x,\infty)$ is empty.

Otherwise stated: each component of the complement of $S$ must either be a bounded half-open interval or an unbounded-on-one-side open interval and $S$ must not just be a singleton.

These conditions are clearly necessary using the first set of conditions: if $x$ is not in the image of an increasing function, then $f^{-1}((-\infty,x))$ and $f^{-1}((x,\infty))$ are disjoint and have union $\mathbb R$ - so either one of these sets is empty, or one of them includes a boundary point, leading to one of the conditions listed.

These conditions are also sufficient, but this direction is harder: the clean way to do this is to axiomatize $\mathbb R$ as a total order and then show that $S$ satisfies the same axioms. An appropriate axiomatization would be as follows:

1. $R$ has at least two elements.
2. $R$ has a countable dense subset $Q$ in the sense that for any $x,y\in R$ with $x<y$ there exists some $z\in Q$ such that $x<z<y$.
3. Every non-empty bounded subset of $R$ has a supremum.
4. $R$ does not have a minimum or maximum element.

You can note that $Q$ has to be order-isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ since it is a countable dense order without minimum or maximum, then see that each element of $R$ is uniquely the supremum of some non-empty closed bounded interval of $Q$ - which one recognizes as the completion of $Q$ by Dedekind cuts. This implies that $R$ is order isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Thus, if we check that $S$ satisfies these conditions, we are done. First, let $\mathscr C$ be the set of bounded components of $\mathbb R\setminus S$. Each of these is a half-open interval $I$, with exactly one endpoint $e_I$ in $S$. Note that $\mathscr C$ is at most countable because each element thereof has positive length and is disjoint from every other element. Let $E=\{e_I : I\in\mathscr C\}$ be the set of these elements and let $Q = E \cup (S\cap \mathbb Q)$.

**Claim:** $Q$ is order-dense in $S$.

**Proof:** Let $x,y\in S$ satisfy $x<y$. Choose any rational $z$ such that $x<z<y$. If $z\in S$ then $z\in Q$ so we are done. Otherwise, let $I\in\mathscr C$ be the interval of the complement of $S$ containing $z$. If $e_I$ is between $x$ and $y$ we are done - otherwise, $e_I$ must equal either $x$ or $y$. In the former case, we have $I=(x,x']$ with $x' < y$. Note too that $x'$ must be the infimum of $S \cap (x,\infty)$ - so we may choose some $s\in S$ such that $x' < s < y$ since $y$ must not be a lower bound of $S \cap (x,\infty)$. If $(x',s)\subseteq S$, we may choose any rational in that interval and observe that it is in $(x,y)\cap Q$. Otherwise, we can choose some $z'\in (x',s)\setminus S$ and let $I'$ be the interval of $\mathscr C$ containing it. Then $e_{I'}$ must be in $[x',s]$ so $x<e_{I'}<y$ in this case. The case where $e_I=y$ proceed similarly by reflecting the argument.

**Claim:** Every non-empty bounded subset of $S$ has a supremum.

**Proof:** Let $B\subseteq S$ be any such subset of $S$ and let $b\in B$ be some element of $B$ and let $u\in S$ be any upper bound to $B$. Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be the supremum of $B$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$. If $x\in S$, then we are done because $x$ must be the supremum of $B$. Otherwise, let $I\in\mathscr C$ be the interval of the complement containing $x$. Note that $x$ must be an endpoint of $I$, since any interval containing $x$ on the interior would contain some element of $B$ as well. In particular, the interval must be of the form $I=[x,x')$ for some $x'>x$. Then $x'\in S$ is the supremum to $B$ in $S$, since every upper bound to $B$ must be at least $x$ and the least such value in $S$ is $x'$. We have therefore found the supremum.

**Claim:** $S$ has no minimum or maximum.

**Proof:** Let $x\in S$. Choose any $y \in \mathbb R$ less than $x$. If $y\in S$, we are done. Otherwise, let $I$ be the component of $\mathbb R\setminus S$ containing $y$. If $I$ is bounded below, then there must be some $z\in S$ with $z<y<x$, so $x$ is not a minimum. Otherwise, $S\cap (-\infty, y)$ is empty, therefore, by the condition, there is no minimum element in $S\cap (y,\infty)$ - also meaning that $x$ is not a minimum. This logic can be repeated symmetrically to see that $x$ is also not a maximum. As $x$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Together, these claims show that $S$ satisfies the order-theoretic axioms that uniquely define $\mathbb R$, hence must be order-isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, meaning there is an increasing bijective map from $\mathbb R$ to $S$. Inherently, this proof **is** constructive, since the order isomorphism between countable dense orders without a minimum or maximum may be determined constructively and then this order isomorphism will be extended in some unique way to the desired one - but the details of doing this are *incredibly* messy and, usually, you don't need such complicated machinery for specific cases you might be interested in.

Note also that it is easy to construct some such $S$ avoiding any measure $0$ set you desire: choose an open set $U$ with finite measure covering the set you wish to avoid. Let $\bar U$ be $U$ union the lesser endpoint of each interval composing $U$. Then $S\setminus \bar U$ satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is good, just choose either of the decimal expansions when you have a choice.  Then $x< x'$ implies that the expansion of $x$ precedes the expansion of $x'$ in lexicographic ordering and you can apply your transformation to continued fractions.

Here is a similar trick that only uses (binary) expansions. Consider for 
every $x \in (0,1]$ the infinite binary  expansion
$$x = \sum_{n\in D_x}\frac{1}{2^n}$$
Now take an increasing map $\phi\colon \{1,2,\ldots,\}\to \{1,2,\ldots\}$
and define
$$f(x) = \sum_{n\in D_x}\frac{1}{2^{\phi(n)}}$$
If $\phi(n) = n^2$, $f$ has all values irrational, while if say $\phi(n) = n!$ then $f$ has all values [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville's_constant)).

Comment: Do I understand correctly? The reason why the choice $\phi(n) =n^2$ leads to a wholly irrational image is because a number is rational if and only if its binary (/decimal) expansion is repeating (or finite)?